# How to open a html file?

Tags: java, html, swing, netbeans, embedded-resource

I have been trying to open a `htmlfile` on clicking help button.   And i need to import the file to source package so after build it wont show errors. I am using `netbeans`.  When i copied the file to `src` and tried running the file it showed error in compiling.  I want to know how to add the file to `src` and how to open by asking the user with a list of browsers installed in the system. Here is the code i have searched and tried..Thanks in advance

```
  try 
  {           
      File htmlFile = new File(this.getClass().getResource("help.html").getFile());
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
  } 
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
      System.out.println(ex);
  }
```

Comment: You have to give us the exception.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Sorry i didn't run that since it shows code is compiled with errors.  If i add the file to `src` package, the code is not compiled successfully

Comment: The the compilation error you have to give us

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam yeah!! For your comment it tried compiling and run the code with error it works.  Then why the `ide` displayed `one or more projects compiled with errors`??? Will it affect after build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FileOpenBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileOpenBrowser"); // set API Name
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); // set Panel Layout

        Button btn = new Button("Help");
        btn.setBounds(50, 100, 60, 30);
        topPanel.add(btn);

        frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Start..");
                    File file = new java.io.File("src/help.html").getAbsoluteFile();
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);                    
                    System.out.println("End..");
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with My Desktop `html` file. now its working fine. 
It will be useful for You.(my default browser is `chrome`)

Try it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FileOpenBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileOpenBrowser"); // set API Name
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); // set Panel Layout

        File urlDesktop = new File(
                "C://Documents and Settings/Hariharan/Desktop/help.html");

        Button btn = new Button("Help");
        btn.setBounds(50, 100, 60, 30);
        topPanel.add(btn);

        frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(urlDesktop);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But after build it definitely show error since you are mentioning path to the file.. But i need to add `.html file` to the `src` folder itself and then invoke it